# MongoDb .Net Driver - Polymorphic Updates Don't Respect CamelCase Convention

Tags: .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using .net driver `2.19.1` with an abstract base class as my document type. I'm using the `CamelCaseElementNameConvention` convention:

```
ConventionRegistry.Register(
    CamelCaseName,
    new ConventionPack { new CamelCaseElementNameConvention() },
    t => true);
```

The camel casing works for properties on the base class. However when I attempt to update a derived property on a document, the property name is serialized in pascal case:

```
public async Task UpdateOneAsync<C>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter,
    string field, C obj)
{
    await _mongoCollection.UpdateOneAsync(filter,
        Builders<T>.Update.Set(field, obj));
}
```

The `field` string here is in pascal - if I manually fix the casing all is well. But I was hoping the convention would do this for me. How can I get properties on derived document classes to respect the convention automatically?

Comment: I tested but convention still works normally to camel when field is pascal.

Comment: which driver version do you use?

Comment: @dododo Added the version to the post.

Comment: AFAIK, the convention pack works for mapping with the model class. In your update query, you provide the field name (first parameter as string), instead of using the model property (with lambda expression).

Comment: Corrected my previous comment, I tested locally, it works when I provide the field name as string to update, the collection document remains the field as camel case. Your issue could happen when either: 1. You didn't enable camel case convention pack before the update query. 2. You are updating (`$set`) the field which doesn't exist in your model class.

Comment: @YongShun Yes I believe you are right. The symptom shows up for properties on derived classes inheriting the document base. Is there some kind of workaround when using polymorphism?